# Как распараллелить вложенные циклы с помощью Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Познавая Java 8 открыл для себя стримы. Решил попробовать распараллелить достаточно долгие вложенные циклы, но столкнулся с проблемой - пока не знаю как.

Вот так выглядит последовательный код:

```
long total = 0;
BitVector vector = getVector(); // из библиотеки import cern.colt.bitvector.*
for (int index = 0; index < vector.size(); index++){
    if (vector.get(index)){
        for (TrafficData trafficData : trafficDataList){

            int visitorTrafficDataIndex = getVisitorTrafficDataIndex(index, trafficData);

            if (visitorTrafficDataIndex >= 0){
                totalTrafficImpressions += (long)(trafficData.getVolume()[visitorTrafficDataIndex]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Думал сделать что-то типа такого:

```
long total = IntStream.range(0, vector.size()).parallel()
        .filter(index -> vector.get(index))
        .mapToLong(index -> 
            trafficDataList.stream()
                .map(trafficData -> getVisitorTrafficDataIndex(index, trafficData))
                .filter(visitorTrafficDataIndex -> visitorTrafficDataIndex >= 0)
                .mapToLong(visitorTrafficDataIndex -> (long)(trafficData.getVolume()[visitorTrafficDataIndex]) // здесь уже нет объекта использовать trafficData 
                .sum())
        ).sum();
```

Проблема в том, что не компилируется..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то надо делать как-то так:

```
long total = IntStream.range( 0, vector.size() ).parallel().filter( index -> vector.get( index ) )
        .mapToLong( index -> trafficDataList.stream().parallel().map( trafficData -> {
            int visitorTrafficDataIndex = getVisitorTrafficDataIndex( index, trafficData );
            if (visitorTrafficDataIndex >= 0) {
                return trafficData.getVolume()[visitorTrafficDataIndex];
            }
            return 0;
        } ).sum() ).sum();
```

Сделать так как хотите вы (всё на стримах) не получится, потому что после того как вы `map(trafficData -> getVisitorTrafficDataIndex(index, trafficData))` в вашем стриме уже нет объекта `trafficData`, он(стрим) уже просто коллекция int.

Comment: спасибо! Помогли разобраться

Comment: Не за что. =) Обращайтесь. PS. Сам же кидался ссылками о том что вектор булевский, и сам же в коде накосячил)